# tableview, adding a row, iphone app, objective c,

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

I have a tableview set up that i can drill down about 3 levels.
I have an edit button at the top that lets me delete rows.
I've just used a mutable array to store data and I can remove items from the array.
This all works fine.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to add a row.
I've been through all the documentation but can't get it working.
I've tried countless things.

I've edited numberOfRowsInSection so that in editing mode it is incremented by 1. But I don't know how to make that row appear.
I want an extra row at the bottom (in editing mode) so that I can add a row.
I just don't know how to get that row on the screen.

If someone has code for a simple tableview, just one view, that has an edit button that allows for adding and deleting a row I'd really appreciate it.
Just can't get my head around something here.

Cheers.
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

You can add new item to array and call `[UITableView reloadData]`.

Or you can use:

```
[tableView beginUpdate];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:*arrayOfIndexPaths* withRowAnimation:*rowAnimation*];
[tableView endUpdate];
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Dyachenko. I'm not sure in which method I should add the new item to the array. Just to be clear I want a green + to appear on a new row with the text "add new row" and when the user touches the + a new row appears that the user can enter text in.